# "DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found" error in importing "kfold" from sklearn

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scikit-learn, k-fold

here I'm encountering strange behavior with VSCode Jupyter notebook!
i can't import `from sklearn.model_selection import KFold` cause it give me ImportError like this:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_30716/370171074.py in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>
     80     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
     81     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
---> 82     from .base import clone
     83     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     84 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>
     15 from . import __version__
     16 from ._config import get_config
---> 17 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     18 from .utils._tags import (
     19     _DEFAULT_TAGS,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>
     21 
     22 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
---> 23 from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight
     24 from . import _joblib
     25 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\class_weight.py in <module>
      5 import numpy as np
      6 
----> 7 from .validation import _deprecate_positional_args
      8 
      9 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in <module>
     24 from contextlib import suppress
     25 
---> 26 from .fixes import _object_dtype_isnan, parse_version
     27 from .. import get_config as _get_config
     28 from ..exceptions import PositiveSpectrumWarning

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in <module>
     18 import scipy.sparse as sp
     19 import scipy
---> 20 import scipy.stats
     21 from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
     22 from numpy.ma import MaskedArray as _MaskedArray  # TODO: remove in 1.0

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py in <module>
    389 
    390 """
--> 391 from .stats import *
    392 from .distributions import *
    393 from .morestats import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in <module>
    172 from numpy import array, asarray, ma
    173 
--> 174 from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
    175 from scipy.ndimage import measurements
    176 from scipy._lib._util import (_lazywhere, check_random_state, MapWrapper,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py in <module>
     96 from .kdtree import *
     97 from .ckdtree import *
---> 98 from .qhull import *
     99 from ._spherical_voronoi import SphericalVoronoi
    100 from ._plotutils import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

**But** when i try this in my CMD (Command Prompt), every thing is okey ! like this :
[image: Importing KFold from model_selection of sklearn]

so how can i fix this problem? any kind of help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which python interpreter you take in the CMD? You can try to switch to it in Jupyter.

It has some problems with the `scipy` package in your conda environment.

You can try this:

```
$> conda remove --force scipy
$> pip install scipy
```

You can refer to this [page](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6396) for more details.

Comment: Thanks ! it worked... ! i don't know how can i figure out about the interpreter that is taken in CMD! how can i know that?
Also Thanks for your referencing !

Comment: @Shayan you can type in 'where python' command in the cmd, the first one is the python interpreter you are taking.